# How do you toggle show/hide in ng-template on Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is what I tried, and of course it makes visible all the items:

```
<ng-template let-file let-i="index" pTemplate="file">
  <div class="ui-fileupload-row">
    <div><img [src]="file.objectURL" width="50"/></div>
    <div>{{file.name}}</div>
    <div>{{formatSize(file.size)}}</div>
    <div><button (click)="toggleIsFormVisible()">Add metadata <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="isFormVisible"></div>
</ng-template>

toggleIsFormVisible()
{
    this.isFormVisible = !this.isFormVisible;
}
```

How do you do this knowing only the index, and without duplicating the items?

Comment: What do you want to show/hide? Can you provide plunker or stackblitz of your example?

Comment: BTW unless you call `toggleIsFormVisible()` from somewhere else, you don't need a function at all, and can inline this into your template: `(click)="isFormVisible = !isFormVisible"`

Comment: @msanford true, thanks

Comment: @GeraldHughes Second side-note: you should _still_ declare a public member variable in your component for it. Some IDEs will complain that it's unused (currently, WebStorm 2018.1 EAP does) but if you don't, it will complain that the variable is unknown in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that solutions was not that complicated, inspired by msanford.

```html
<ng-template let-file let-i="index" pTemplate="file">
  <div class="ui-fileupload-row">
    <div><img [src]="file.objectURL" width="50"/></div>
    <div>{{file.name}}</div>
    <div>{{formatSize(file.size)}}</div>
    <div><button (click)="file.isFormVisible = !file.isFormVisible">Add metadata <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="file.isFormVisible"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `this.isFormVisible`
2. `ngIf="IsFormVisible"`

The issue is with capitalized `i` letter.

Comment: If I am not mistaking, this kind of errors show up on the browser's console, right?

Comment: Thanks, but not the issue here.